# Confliting PORTNO of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I have installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.32 and I am using Eclipse JUNO. But whenever I am using Eclipse I am not getting result from Server rather than I am getting Server can not start within 45sec.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing connection port in `server.xml`

Comment: Didn't work? So let us know that. And if worked accept the answer.